# Estes Rate Quote PHP SOAP Requst returning error

Tags: php, soap, soap-client, estes-express-api

I have been attempting to get this to work for a while.  I am hoping someone familiar with it happens to run across the question and can explain WHY this isnt working and what is wrong with the code.  Estes has been useless in helping thus far.  They have provided me a bunch of information but none of it works.

The code below is returning this error

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] SOAP-ERROR:
>   Encoding: object has no 'requestID' property in
>   /home/xxxxxxxxxx/public_html/inc/estes/estesapi.php:41 Stack trace: #0
>   /home/xxxxxxxxxx/public_html/inc/estes/estesapi.php(41):
>   SoapClient->__call('getQuote', Array) #1 {main} thrown in
>   /home/xxxxxxxxxx/public_html/inc/estes/estesapi.php on line 41

```
$client = new SoapClient("https://www.estes-express.com/tools/rating/ratequote/v3.0/services/RateQuoteService?wsdl");

    $request_object = array(
     "header"=>array(
          "auth"=>array(
                "user"=>"xxxxxxxxx",
                "password"=>"xxxx",
                )
          ),

          "rateRequest"=>array(
                "requestID"=>"abc",
                "account"=>"############",

            "originPoint"=>array(
                "countryCode"=>"US",
                "postalCode"=>"28366",
                "city"=>"Newton Grove",
                "stateProvince"=>"NC",
          ),
            "destinationPoint"=>array(
                "countryCode"=>"US",
                "postalCode"=>"28334",
          ),
          "payor"=> "S",
          "terms"=> "P",
          "stackable"=> "N",
            "baseCommodities"=>array(
                "commodity"=>array(
                    "class"=>"50",
                    "weight"=>"1200",
                )
            )
 )

        );

        $result = $client->getQuote($request_object);

        var_dump($result);

print_r($result);
```

I cant figure out why RequestID isnt being passed into the soap request.

Comment: Why are you passing all the data to `header' attribute ?

Comment: Header ends on line 9

Comment: Yeah you right. My experience working with SOAP is that the doc sometimes doesnt match the WSDL files. So read the WSDL files and check the required parameters

Comment: I wish there was more documentation.  The documentation isn’t great and doesn’t go into any specifics and the company “doesn’t know php” and can’t help any further.  :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is our Estes Soap call. See if you see anything in it that helps:

```
// define transaction arrays
$url = "http://www.estes-express.com/rating/ratequote/services/RateQuoteService?wsdl";
$username = 'xxxxxxxx';
$password = 'xxxxxxxx';

// setting a connection timeout of five seconds
$client = new SoapClient($url, array("trace" => true,
         "exceptions" => true,
         "connection_timeout" => 5,
         "features" => SOAP_WAIT_ONE_WAY_CALLS,
         "cache_wsdl" => WSDL_CACHE_NONE));
    $old = ini_get('default_socket_timeout');
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 5);

//Prepare SoapHeader parameters
$cred = array(
    'user'      => $username,
    'password'  => $password
);

$header = new SoapHeader('http://ws.estesexpress.com/ratequote', 'auth', $cred);
$client->__setSoapHeaders($header);

$params = array(
    "requestID"         => "xxxxxxxx",
    "account"           => "xxxxxxxx",
    "originPoint"       => array('countryCode' => 'US', 'postalCode' => $fromzip),
    "destinationPoint"  => array('countryCode' => 'US', 'postalCode' => $shipzip),
    "payor"             => 'T',
    "terms"             => 'PPD',
    "stackable"         => 'N',
            "baseCommodities"   => array('commodity' => $comArray ),
            "accessorials"      => array('accessorialCode' => $accArray)
);
    // remove accessorials entry if no accessorial codes
    if(count($accArray) == 0){
        $params = array_slice($params, 0, 8); // remove accesorials entry
    }

 // call Estes API and catch any errors
    try {
 $reply = $client->getQuote($params);
}
catch(SoapFault $e){
       // handle issues returned by the web service
       //echo "Estes soap fault<br>" . $e . "<br>";
       $edit_error_msg = "Estes quote API timed out or failed to return a quote";
         return "0.00";
}
catch(Exception $e){
       // handle PHP issues with the request
       //echo "PHP soap exception<br>" . $e . "<br>";
         $edit_error_msg = "Estes quote API timed out or failed to return a quote";
         return "0.00";
}
    unset($client);
  ini_set('default_socket_timeout', $old);

 // print_r($reply);
```

Comment: You don't perhaps have an Estes Bill of Lading api set up do you?

Comment: No, our shipper does that.

Comment: what about an estes tracking?  Do you perhaps have the code for that?  I tried modifying this but not getting a response back.